# handlebars.js “each” loop inside another “each”

Tags: handlebars.js

I have two objects. 1 object is 10 questions, 2 object is 10 answers, I need to output them in nested loops, but that doesn't work.

```
 {{#each questions}}
     {{#each answers}}
         <p class = "mt-2"> {{this.text}} </p>
         <p> {{this.value}} </p>
     {{/ each}}
 {{/ each}}
```

I also tried this option:

```
 {{#each questions}}
     {{#each ../answers}}
         <p class = "mt-2"> {{../ this.text}} </p>
         <p> {{this.value}} </p>
     {{/ each}}
 {{/ each}}
```

but in this case, each question-answer is displayed 10 times. I tried different options so many times

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that you've nested two loops. This means that for each question, it will output all the answers every time.

If I'm reading your question right, you're trying to output `question1, answer1, question2, answer2, etc.`, so you'll have to instead look up the corresponding answer inside the loop using an `@index`.

This can be done using `{{#with (lookup ../answers @index)}}` to change the context like so:

```
 {{#each questions}}
     <p class = "mt-2"> {{this.text}} </p>
     <p> {{this.value}} </p>
     {{#with (lookup ../answers @index)}}
     <p class = "mt-2"> {{text}} </p>
     <p> {{value}} </p>
     {{/with}}
 {{/ each}}
```